# Can we write selectors by only name of elements in CSS File

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can we write  selectors by only name

For example,

```
<div name= "outer-name">
    <img name="inner-image" src="images/ine.jpg" alt"" />
</div>
```

I want to take style of inner-mage in css file like   [outer-name] [inner-image]

In CSS file

```
[outer-name] [inner-image] {
    /*styles*/
}
```

I cant take selector as [outer-name] img etc .. only selecting by name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors:

```
[name="outer-name"] [name="inner-image"]
```

But keep in mind that `name` is not a valid attribute for `<div>` or `<img>`, even though the above selector will work. It's best that you either change them to classes, or if you're using HTML5, add the `data-` prefix to them, so it looks like this:

```
<div data-name= "outer-name">
    <img data-name="inner-image" src="images/ine.jpg" alt"" />
</div>
```

Then use this selector:

```
[data-name="outer-name"] [data-name="inner-image"]
```

Comment: is there anything you don't know about css boltclock? ;)

Comment: @stephenmurdoch: BoltClock knows how to implement CSS6 parent-selector notation, but isn't telling us, because no browser can yet keep up with him.

Comment: It is not possible to give as class due to some reasons. Then tried with id to style ,but I have heard about 'id collision' in different pages(don't have enough idea).That is why ,I stick to name attribute

Comment: I can't think of any good reason that you can include arbitrary attributes yet not classes. Use HTML5 `data-*` attributes, maybe? Then it'll validate, plus you can be confident that modern browsers will play well with it.

Comment: @BoltClock: An class="mod_article freetrialbanner showcase partner-logos partner-text ce_text block block", Its already 7 classes in a div , now i am trying reduce number of classes used or atleast avoid to create new classes. These classes are created by other guys and used in varoius places.Any change in that will reflect in other places

Answer (score 3):

Given the following html:

```
<div data-name="something">
    <p>Content in 'something'</p>
    <span data-someAttribute="someAttribute">Content in 'someAttribute' div.</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
[data-name] {
    background-color: red;
}

[data-name] [data-someAttribute] {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

This is perfectly valid (or, at least, it's implemented in Chromium 14/Ubuntu 11.04). I've changed from using `name` attributes (since they're invalid for `div` elements, or other non-`form` elements), and used, instead, `data-*` prefixed custom attributes, which are valid in HTML5 and, while perhaps not 'valid' in HTML 4, they seem to be understood by those browsers still.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xBxKa/1/).

It's worth noting that you can also use attribute=equals notation, to select only certain elements based on the value of their `data-*` attributes:

```
<div data-name="something">
    <p>Content in data-name='something' element.</p>
    <span data-someAttribute="someAttribute">Content in 'someAttribute' div.</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
[data-name] {
    background-color: red;
}

[data-name="something"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}

[data-name] [data-someAttribute] {
    background-color: #ffa;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xBxKa/2/).

Also, if CSS3 is an option for you, it's possible to use attribute-begins-with (`^=`) notation:

```
[data-name] {
    background-color: red;
}

[data-name^="s"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}

[data-name] [data-someAttribute] {
    background-color: #ffa;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xBxKa/3/).

And attribute-ends-with (`$=`) notation:

```
[data-name] {
    background-color: red;
}

[data-name$="ing"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}

[data-name] [data-someAttribute] {
    background-color: #ffa;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

References:

- [`data-*` attributes (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).
- [`data-*` attributes, (HTML5 Doctor)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).
- [attribute-equals selector (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors).
- [attribute-starts-with, and attribute-ends-with selectors (W3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings).

Comment: +1 for the references.  If you add the `[data-name="something"]` to your examples, I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bolt said, `name` isn't valid there (yet it still works on my browser).  You can use the HTML5 `data-` properties.  Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sde6t/1/) showing how it's done.

The real solution here would be to use classes, but I assume you have a reason for not using them.

Comment: Browsers are pretty lenient, and the CSS spec doesn't enforce the same attribute restrictions that HTML does, which could explain why it works :)